# how to mask some text in radtextbox

Tags: c#, mask, maskedtextbox, radtextbox

I need to mask a input string having Pan number format ex.(ABCDE1234F) to (######234F) .

I have tried using maskedtextbox but it didn't help.

using below code :-

Comment: I think you forgot to add code

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code, you can modify this code as per the textbox values

```
var cardNumber = "ABCDE1234F";

var firstDigits = cardNumber.Substring(0, 5);
Console.WriteLine(firstDigits);

var lastDigits = cardNumber.Substring(cardNumber.Length - 5, 5);
Console.WriteLine(lastDigits);

var requiredMask = new String('#', cardNumber.Length - firstDigits.Length);
Console.WriteLine(requiredMask);

var maskedString = string.Concat(requiredMask, lastDigits);
Console.WriteLine(maskedString);
```

Output

```
ABCDE
1234F
#####
#####1234F
```

Answer (score 0):

Add event OnTextChanged to your textbox with below code

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
    {
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(0, 6).PadLeft(10, '#');
    }
}
```